# Two Lower X axes matplot lib

Tags: matplotlib, axis

I was wondering if it is possible to have two distinct X axes in matplotlib, but not so that they are on opposite sides of the graph. Instead, would it be possible to put them next to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image: Two x-axes on the bottom.]

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

par2 = host.twiny()

offset = -40
new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["bottom"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="bottom",
                                     axes=par2,
                                     offset=(0, offset))

par2.axis["top"].toggle(all=False)

host.set_xlim(0, 2)
host.set_ylim(0, 2)

host.set_ylabel("Distance")
host.set_xlabel("Density")
par2.set_xlabel("Velocity")

p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], label="Density")
p3, = par2.plot([50, 30, 15], [0, 1, 2], label="Velocity")

par2.set_xlim(1, 65)

host.legend()

host.axis["bottom"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par2.axis["bottom"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I be able to do this so that the X axis are horizontally next to each other?

Comment: When you say 'next to' do you mean 'above and below'?

Comment: If you supply example code (that is complete) and explain why it is not doing what you want I could be more helpful.

Comment: I do not have code right now, but i meean next to each other as in on the same horizontal axis, like two numberlines next to each other.

Comment: In the future you will get a better response if you take the time to create some example code. It wasn't that hard to modify the code I supplied to create this figure. Look at it this way: you are asking a community of people--whose time is valuable--to help you with a problem. Take the time to pose a GOOD question so that you don't waste their time. In this case, you got lucky because I am trying to build my reputation on this site, but most people will ignore this kind of question. For more information, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask